# What configuration files change when installing SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-config

SharePoint is installed on the root Folder of IIS, sub-sites are in a folder under the root, and it's running on a Server 2008 R2 machine.

To start, i'm asking this question because after installing SharePoint 2013, other applications on sub-sites stopped working correctly.  Specifically, the PHP pages still worked, but all the ASPX pages stopped and the error would refer to SharePoint references in the web.config (or another config file).

So my question is, when SharePoint 2013 is first installed, what configuration files does it change that could affect all the sites/sub-sites on the same server?

I should point out that I've checked the web.config file for any affected pages, double checked the application pool is setup right, and even checked the global web.config and machine.config in the C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0*\config folder.  I have not found any SharePoint references in any config file besides the one in the root folder that SharePoint is installed to.

I'm not as familiar with how the web.config affects other sites as well, so if it is the main web.config in the root folder in IIS, could you explain how that affects the sub-sites, and if there is any way to separate the two without putting them on separate domains/servers?  Thanks.

Here's the last exception i was getting, which includes some of the references I see:

```
Exception type: PlatformNotSupportedException 
Exception message: Operation is not supported on this platform.
at System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Set(String name, String value)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache.ReadToken(Byte[] token)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Just to note, in the exception, all i have found for that message is to make the application pool integrated instead of classic, but then the sub-sites stop working.  I'm going with the assumption I can get it to work if i can find out where it's getting the references from.

Comment: Did you made any changes in web.config before updates? Also did you make any changes in hive folders?

Comment: Also, did you upgrade ur application from other sharepoint versions to 2013?

Comment: No changes to the web.config before or after, it went from working, then installed SharePoint, and then noticed errors only shown up on ASPX pages for the sub-sites that were affected (SharePoint pages worked fine though).  SharePoint was not installed on the server before, so this is a fresh install of SharePoint 2013.